# ASP.NET Core XUnit replace service with parameter (DI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I'm new to XUnit and I'm trying to configure my test project with new appsettings and a service. 
The service accepts the appsettings class in the constructor.

In my startup file from my api project I have the following:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
var appSettings = _configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)).Get<AppSettings>();

services.AddScoped<ILogging, MailLogging>(s => new MailLogging(appSettings));
```

This works for my API, but now I want to emplement it in my XUnit project (but with a different appsettings file)

```
var appsettings = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                 .Build()
                 .GetSection("AppSettings");

builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appsettings)
);
```

This works, but when I try to implement the new MailLogging, I'm getting NullExceptions when using data from AppSettings in the service. (both lines in comment don't work)

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                //services.AddScoped<ILogging, MailLogging>(s => new MailLogging(appsettings as AppSettings))
                //services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<ILogging, MailLogging>(s => new MailLogging(appsettings as AppSettings)))
            );
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method instead:

```
var appsettingsSection = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                 .Build()
                 .GetSection("AppSettings");

var appSettings = new AppSettings();
appsettingsSection.Bind(appSettings);

builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    services.AddSingleton(appSettings);
    services.AddScoped<ILogging, MailLogging>(s => new MailLogging(appsettings)
);
```

Comment: This gives an error at services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettings) => Can't bind AppSettings to system.action<AppSettings>. + How should I construct my logging service then?

Comment: I have updated the answer, try it and let me it does work or not.